# Exit code (Decimal) -2068054016 SqlServer. Como puedo solucionar?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Exit code (Decimal)
-2068054016
Error description
El sistema no puede en[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]contrar la ruta especifica

Comment: Hola Andres, bienvenido a SOes, podrías darnos mayores detalles por favor? Sistema operativo, estabas realizando una instalación desde cero? estabas dando un upgrade al SQL Server 2014? El instalador era un .iso?

Comment: El instalador de SQL genera siempre un log que contiene los detalles, puedes inspeccionarlo para encontrar mayor información sobre este error en particular. En la imagen que publicas se ve la ruta donde esta instalación en particular dejó el LOG.

Comment: La instalación se esta haciendo desde cero es de SqlServer versión 2016 se estaba haciendo en el sistema operativo windows 8.1 la , se descargo el archivo ejecutable .exe que proporciona windows sql server en su pagina web.

Comment: tengo exactamente el mismo problema..alguien sabe como solucionarlo?